# Misplaced container when app started in landscape IOS

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard

I'm developing dictionary for IOS and can't understand why on my iPad in landscape orientation my app start with replaced container view, at simulator all good. But when I change current tab on iPad all become exactly what I want.

**On iPad app started in landscape:**
[image: in iPad app started in landscape]

**After change tabs:**
[image: After change tabs]

**On simulator all going right at start:**
[image: On simulator all going right]

Any suggestions?

**Edit**
Top of container aligned to searchBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If iPad OS is iOS 6, and you write nib-file for right controller as iOS7-view, you need to alignement by top behind, not the bottom status bar. For iOS 7 do all origin by Y for +20.

Comment: iPad iOS 7, I'm using storyboard, and I have adMob view above.

Comment: Thanks, I saw at container, but I need to check controller for container.